# SEO - Redirect Hop Counting Site Spider Tool

Tags: redirect, seo, count, web-crawler

Anyone know of any available code to spider a site, track hops, redirects, type of redirects etc?

Or a hopefully free tool?

The Reason I'm trying to do this is to clean up a site thats pages have accumulated several redirects over the years.

I've googled and googled to no avail.. I found tools that would check a page only if you provided the links.. but not a "spider" tool..

thank you

Answer (score 0):

For something similar, I have used JSpider - http://j-spider.sourceforge.net/